# Enabling Enable-PSRemoting on Powershell 1.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

This is in relation to http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_remote.htm . Currently, most of the machines in my Test environment are on Powershell 1.0. Under such a scenario, is there a way by which I can still manage to make **remote calls via Powershell** from one machine to another.
My ultimate motive is to **start/stop/restart a windows service remotely** using Powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use PowerShell Remoting in 1.0, but you *can* [use WMI](http://blog.geekpoet.net/2008/10/manipulating-remote-services-with.html) or [.Net ServiceController](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/01/03/powershell-using-net-to-manage-remote-services.aspx) for this task.

```
$S = Get-WmiObject -Computer $Server -Class win32_service -filter "name='$ServiceName'"
$S.StopService()
$S.StartService()
```

In fact, if you have 2.0 on the client you're on, you can skip a couple of steps versus the way it's written on either of those posts by using Invoke-WMIMethod:

```
Invoke-WMIMethod -Name StopService -Computer $Server -Class win32_service -filter "name='$ServiceName'" 

Invoke-WMIMethod -Name StartService -Computer $Server -Class win32_service -filter "name='$ServiceName'"
```

**Note: for general remoting, you could set up an SSH server on each box** and remote in that way (and set up PowerShell as the default shell), [/n software has a pre-built solution](http://powershellinside.com/powershell/ssh/) around that.